# How to use specific version of external library in jsfiddle?

Tags: highcharts, jsfiddle

I want to run some simple example from highcharts but with the previous of Highcharts library. This is the example what I mean:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/basic-line/
```

The previous version is available at:

```
http://code.highcharts.com/stock/1.2.5/highstock.js
http://code.highcharts.com/stock/1.2.5/modules/exporting.js
```

When I replace the links in `script` tag, the chart is not generated. The same when I use `External Resources` and pase the links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fiddle you are using includes the new jQuery-ish container methods like:

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
```

This not supported below v1.3. You will need to modify the code to do something like:

```
window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/cVScv/) for basic example.